# <map> tag coordinate attribute

Tags: html

```
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to find these coordinates and how shape affected the results

Comment: i didnt undrestant what you mean